# How can I select the record in the grid view and delete or edit this record? In Asp.Net Web Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

How can I select the record in the grid view and delete or edit this record? In Asp.Net Web Form

I want this to be done with the Bootstrap modal

I do this with Entity Framework

I have only been able to code to add

The methods I know for editing and deleting are not suitable for this project and they do not work on Bootstrap Modal

Html Code:

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ProductControl.aspx.cs" Inherits="AppData.Pages.ProductControl" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeadContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="Head" runat="server">
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/Site.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 table-responsive" id="ProductDiv">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3 mt-3">
                    <h4>List of Products</h4>
                    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalAdd">
                                Add Product
                            </button>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>


                <asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" CssClass="table text-center table-bordered table-hover" HeaderStyle-CssClass="table-dark" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="Id" OnRowCommand="GridView_RowCommand">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Font-Size="Small">
                            <HeaderTemplate>Row</HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate><%# Container.DataItemIndex+1 %></ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Barcode" HeaderText="Barcode" />

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Commands" ItemStyle-Font-Size="Small">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-warning" ID="BtnEdit" runat="server">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-danger" ID="BtnDelete" runat="server" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalDelete">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-info" ID="BtnDetail" runat="server">Detail</asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <asp:Label ID="LblNotFound" runat="server" Text="No Product Found" CssClass="col-12 alert alert-danger text-center" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal Add -->

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelModalAdd" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="modal" id="ModalAdd">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Record</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p>Name:</p>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Name" placeholder="Name" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p>Price:</p>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Price" placeholder="Price" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <br />
                                        <p>Type:</p>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Type" placeholder="Type" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <br />
                                        <p>Barcode:</p>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Barcode" placeholder="Barcode" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <asp:Button ID="BtnCreate" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="Create" OnClick="BtnCreate_Click" />
                                <asp:Button ID="BtnCancel" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger" Text="Cancel" data-dismiss="modal" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnCreate" EventName="Click" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnCancel" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>


        <!-- Modal Detail -->

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelModalDetail" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="modal" id="ModalDetail">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Detail Record</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p>Name:</p>
                                        <asp:Label ID="LblName" CssClass="text-secondary" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p>Price:</p>
                                        <asp:Label ID="LblPrice" CssClass="text-secondary" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <br />
                                        <p>Type:</p>
                                        <asp:Label ID="LblType" CssClass="text-secondary" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <br />
                                        <p>Barcode:</p>
                                        <asp:Label ID="LblBarcode" CssClass="text-secondary" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="Create" OnClick="BtnCreate_Click" />
                                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger" Text="Cancel" data-dismiss="modal" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <!-- Modal Delete -->

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelModalDelete" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="modal" id="ModalDelete">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Record</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <h6 class="text-center">Are you sure you want to delete this record?</h6>
                                <br />
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <asp:Button ID="Delete" CssClass="btn btn-danger border-2 border-dark" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CommandName="Delete" />
                                    <button id="Cancel" class="btn btn-light border-2 border-dark" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Delete" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

And Backend Code:

```
using AppData.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.EnterpriseServices;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace AppData.Pages
{
    public partial class ProductControl : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Models.ProductDbEntities Db = new Models.ProductDbEntities();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (GridView.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                LblNotFound.Visible = false;
            }

            else
            {
                GridView.DataSource = Db.TblProducts.ToList();
                GridView.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void BtnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TblProduct Row = new TblProduct();

            Row.Name = Name.Text;
            Row.Price = Price.Text;
            Row.Type = Type.Text;
            Row.Barcode = Convert.ToInt64(Barcode.Text);

            Db.TblProducts.Add(Row);
            Db.SaveChanges();

            Response.Redirect("ProductControl.aspx");
        }

        protected void BtnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Pages/ProductControl.aspx");
        }

        protected void GridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            var id = e.CommandArgument;

            if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
            {
                Int64 Id = Convert.ToInt64(id);
                var Row = Db.TblProducts.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Id == Id);

                Db.TblProducts.Remove(Row);
                Db.SaveChanges();

                Response.Redirect("DataControl.aspx");
                GridView.DataSource = Db.TblProducts.ToList();
                GridView.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your approach, but if you are using bootstrap modals you need to write a little bit more code.

One way to achieve this is by following the next steps:

1. In the **Delete modal** add a hidden field to hold the selected productId and an event handler for the delete button:

```
  <div class="modal-body">
     <h6 class="text-center">Are you sure you want to delete this record?</h6>
      <br />
      <!--add this inside delete modal --> 
      <input type="hidden" id="productIdToDelete" runat="server" />
                                
      <div class="text-center">
      <!-- remove CommandArgument and CommandName from the Delete button. They are useless in the popup. -->
      <!-- add an event handler to OnClick-->
      <asp:Button ID="Delete" CssClass="btn btn-danger border-2 border-dark" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="BtnDelete_Click"  />
...
```

2. **Create event handlers** for when the modal is opened in order **to propagate the productId** from the current row in the grid to the modal:

```
 <script src="../Scripts/Site.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            //use a jquery selector to assign an event handler to all Delete Buttons found on the page (nottice they all start with the same prexif)
            $("[id*=MainContent_GridView_BtnDelete]").click(function () {
                //get the id of the product from the selected row first cell and assign it to the hidden field in the modal
                $("#MainContent_productIdToDelete").val($(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).html());
            });
        });
</script>
```

3. Finally, **handle the delete event** in the code behind:

```
protected void BtnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string idVal = Request.Form[productIdToDelete.UniqueID];
    var id = Convert.ToInt64(idVal);
    // implement delete logic ...
}
```

Use the same approach for Edit. (Look at [this example](https://www.aspsnippets.com/questions/196513/Display-GridView-selected-row-value-in-Bootstrap-modal-in-ASPNet/).)

Comment: Db.TblProducts.Remove(?);
            Db.SaveChanges();   What should I delete?

Comment: You use the id to find the row that you need to remove: `var row = Db.TblProducts.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Id==id); if(row != null) { Db.TblProducts.Remove(row); Db.SaveChanges(); }`

Comment: string idVal = Request.Form[productIdToDelete.UniqueID];
var id = Convert.ToInt64(idVal);
var Row = Db.TblProducts.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Id == id);
if (Row != null)
{
Db.TblProducts.Remove(Row);
Db.SaveChanges();
Response.Redirect("ProductControl.aspx");

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
            function () {
                //use a jquery selector to assign an event handler to all Delete Buttons found on the page (nottice they all start with the same prexif)
                $("[id*=MainContent_GridView_BtnDelete]").click(function () {
                    //get the id of the product from the selected row first cell and assign it to the hidden field in the modal
                    $("#MainContent_productIdToDelete").val($(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).html());
                });
});
</script>

Comment: they don't work

Comment: Important note: I am using asp:updatepanel

Comment: what error do you receive?

Comment: I do not get any error, only the desired record is not deleted

Comment: When you debug the code, are you able to hit a breakpoint inside the BtnDelete_Click method ?